# Time-based triggers controlled by sheet interface not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am attempting to build an interface on a Google Sheets that allows the user to adjust time-based triggers in the application's script. Unfortunately, none of the triggers are firing or being recognized as triggers.

I have attempted revising the script a few times but nothing appears to be working.

```
// Creates the first trigger
function trigger1(){
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();            
var dd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dashboard = dd.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
var triggerDay1 = dashboard.getRange(5,3).getValue();
//Logger.log(triggerDay1);
ScriptApp.newTrigger("emailReminders")
  .timeBased()
  .at(triggerDay)
  .create();
}
```

Someone can click a date in a Google Sheets and the trigger will fire on the date chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

As is, Your function is using both "triggerDay1" and "triggerDay", so there isn't anything being entered into the trigger call.

added to

```
function trigger1(){
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();            
var dd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dashboard = dd.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
var triggerDay1 = dashboard.getRange(5,3).getValue();
Logger.log(triggerDay1);
ScriptApp.newTrigger("emailReminders")
  .timeBased()
  .at(triggerDay1)
  .create();
}
```

If there are still issues I'd play with the formatting of your date, you might have to plug the value from triggerDay1 into a date variable.

```
triggerDay = new Date(triggerDay1);
```

Comment: Greetings, I have attempted these suggestions to my script and I am still achieving nothing. The trigger isn't recognized in the Gsuite developer hub. I have also attempted to skip the date picker in the sheet and create a time-based trigger directly in the developer hub and that too hasn't worked. Is this an effort worth attempting?